# sending email using Java mail Api with app deployed in tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, tomcat

I am trying to send email using java Mail Api + Spring-boot Application.
The properties which are being used are :

```
mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: niranjan.numeroeins@gmail.com
    password: msiyyyyyvzcbox # App password for less secure web app procured
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
      auth: true
      starttls.enable: true
      ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

The above config works with my spring-boot+JavaMail Api nicely when i run jar directly using "java -jar myJar.jar". But once the application is deployed inside tomcat container it starts giving error as it would if you are trying to access Gmail server with less secure app like our web app code . Looks like some config issue on tomcat side(using tomcat-9)? Please help . Here is the log trace :

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is jav
ax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials j22sm1775206pjz.3 - gsmtp
```

Please note that you will get same error if you try sending the email with actual password and not App password https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: After finding  a lot  didn't find answer for above question , but you can get through this  by using java+gmailapi+oauth2 , here is the starting point https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server and one youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ1ZEjuJF8U